# How to accelerate tensorflow Dataset.load and make use all available resources?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a relatively large dataset of a size of ~1.8TB. Aiming to optimize the data feeding process while training the model, I first preprocessed all the data and stored them into 1200 separate **`tensorflow`** datasets with 1024 samples in each of them. The sample shape is (512, 768). Data type is **`tf.float32`** .

To load the data I use Python loop, **`Dataset.load()`** and **`Dataset().concatenate`** functions:

```
# I put datasets 0000..0959 into training dataset
train_data = Dataset.load(f'tf/0000')
for i in range(1,960):
    train_data = train_data.concatenate(Dataset.load(f'tf/{str(i).zfill(4)}'))

# And the datasets 0960..1199 into validaion dataset
valid_data = Dataset.load(f'tf/0960')
for i in trange(961, 1200):
    valid_data = valid_data.concatenate(Dataset.load(f'tf/{str(i).zfill(4)}'))
```

The labels are stored separately as a **`Numpy`** file. There is only one label for each sample, so to merge the features and labels, I put labels into the memory and zip them with the features:

```
labels = np.load('tf/y.npy').astype(np.float32)
train_labels = labels[0:960*1024]
valid_labels = labels[960*1024:1200*1024]

train_data = Dataset.zip((train_data, Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_labels)))
valid_data = Dataset.zip((valid_data, Dataset.from_tensor_slices(valid_labels)))
```

I tried using different batch sizes and prefetch parameters, but it didn't impact the performance. Here is the current version:

```
train_data = train_data.batch(256)
train_data = train_data.prefetch(4)
valid_data = valid_data.batch(64)
valid_data = valid_data.prefetch(4)
```

Everything about the model in this example is as simple as possible:

```
def create_model(input_shape):
    
    inp = Input(input_shape)
    f1 = Flatten()(inp)
    do1 = Dropout(0.2)(f1)
    d1 = Dense(1024)(do1)
    do2 = Dropout(0.2)(d1)
    out = Dense(1, activation='linear')(do2)
    model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
    return model

model = create_model((512,768))
model.compile(optimizer = Adam(), loss = 'mse')
model.fit(train_data, validation_data = valid_data, epochs = 10)
```

The progress bar indicates that 1 epoch is gonna take 2-3 hours while neither CPU nor GPU is fully loaded.

I use the virtual machine: **8 vCPUs, 30 GB RAM, T4 GPU**. I use **Python 3.7.12** and **tensorflow 2.10.0**

Utilization metrics are:

**CPU:** stable ~6% (1 vCPU, I guess)

**RAM:** stable ~38% used; ~60% cached; ~2% free

**GPU:** hops from 0 to 15-20%

So I want to find the bottleneck and fix the code to make it use all resources.

I've tried to change the batch size and prefetch parameter but it had zero effect.

I've also tried to set **`tf.data.ThreadingOptions()`** after **`prefetch()`**:

```
options = tf.data.Options()
options.threading.private_threadpool_size = 10
train_data = train_data.with_options(options)
```

But it didn't help too.

I've looked into this - [Looping over tf.data.Dataset very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62453823/looping-over-tf-data-dataset-very-slow) and tried to wrap model fitting into **`@tf.function`**:

```
@tf.function
def train(model, train_data, valid_data):
    model.fit(train_data, validation_data = valid_data, epochs = 10)

train(model, train_data, valid_data)
```

But it raised an error:

```
RuntimeError: Detected a call to `Model.fit` inside a `tf.function`. `Model.fit is a high-level endpoint that manages its own `tf.function`. Please move the call to `Model.fit` outside of all enclosing `tf.function`s. Note that you can call a `Model` directly on `Tensor`s inside a `tf.function` like: `model(x)`.
```

Finally, I've experimented with **`workers`** and **`use_multiprocessing`** parameters of the **`model.fit()`** method, but it changed nothing.

A have also read these questions:

- [Why is TensorFlow's `tf.data` package slowing down my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51541610/why-is-tensorflows-tf-data-package-slowing-down-my-code)
- [Tensorflow Dataset extremely slow compared to queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47652590/tensorflow-dataset-extremely-slow-compared-to-queues)

But I didn't find them relevant

Comment: Did you try creating tfrecords with both data and labels together?. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427637/numpy-to-tfrecords-is-there-a-more-simple-way-to-handle-batch-inputs-from-tfrec

Comment: You could try profiling: [Analyze tf.data performance with the TF Profiler](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance_analysis)